# Facing issue in taking llvm ir file via command line argument

Tags: c++, c++11, llvm, llvm-ir

I am writing the program `hello.cpp` taking the refernece from the example of Chapter 3 of Getting Started with LLVM Core Libraries book.

I want to take LLVM IR file `input.bc` as command line argument. But I do not know how to do it. I am trying: `g++ hello.cpp -I /tmp/llvm/include/ -std=c++11   input.bc` It is showing error :

```
input.bc: file not recognized: File format not recognized     
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my source code of `hello.cpp`

```
#include "llvm/Bitcode/BitcodeReader.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"
#include "llvm/Support/ErrorOr.h"
#include "llvm/Support/MemoryBuffer.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"

using namespace llvm;

static cl::opt<std::string>
FileName(cl::Positional, cl::desc("Bitcode file"), cl::Required);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(argc, argv, "LLVM hello world\n");
  LLVMContext context;

  ErrorOr<std::unique_ptr<MemoryBuffer>> mb = MemoryBuffer::getFile(FileName);
  if (std::error_code ec = mb.getError()) {
    errs() << ec.message();
    return -1;
  }

//  ErrorOr<Module *> m = parseBitcodeFile(mb->get(), context);
//  if (std::error_code ec = m.getError()) {
  Expected<std::unique_ptr<Module>> m = parseBitcodeFile(mb->get()->getMemBufferRef(), context);
        if (std::error_code ec = errorToErrorCode(m.takeError())) {
    errs() << "Error reading bitcode: " << ec.message() << "\n";
    return -1;
  }
for (Module::const_iterator I = (*m)->getFunctionList().begin(),
    E = (*m)->getFunctionList().end(); I != E; ++I) {
    if (!I->isDeclaration()) {
      outs() << I->getName() << " has " << I->size() << " basic blocks.\n";
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: g++ hello.cpp -I /tmp/llvm/include/ -std=c++11   input.bc means you are trying to compile two files hello.cpp and input.bc, do you have input.bc? also .bc is bitcode file is in context of llvm bitcode and g++ does not natively support that, probably check again is it 'clang' and some flags are missing i guess.

Comment: @ChiragPatel, Yes I have `input.bc` by converting  input.c via clang and then llvm-as . So will you please tell me what is the way to compile hello.cpp which take the inpput.bc as command line argument?

Comment: probably after reading your c++ code it try, g++ hello.cpp -o hello then ./hello input.bc.

Comment: @ChiragPatel, I tried : `g++ main.cpp -I /tmp/llvm/include/ -std=c++11` But it is showing same one of error: `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: main.cpp??? is it a new file?

Comment: @ChiragPatel, ohh sorry `g++ hello.cpp -I /tmp/llvm/include/ -std=c++11`

Comment: hello.cpp is dependent on llvm libraries and headers so you need to pass those as well, like g++ <some cxx flags> <some include paths> <some libraries path> <some linker flags> hello.cpp -o hello, there is a very nice utility provided with llvm 'llvm-config'  you can look into, http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-config.html

Comment: Have you tried throwing "llvm" and the error into the search field up top? It turns up a bunch of similar questions...

Comment: @ChiragPatel, Thanks a lott for suggesting,it works. I am posting answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got my answer. I need to specify libraries and compiler flags while compiling.

> To Compile:  g++  -std=c++11  -I /tmp/llvm/include/  `llvm-config --cxxflags` hello.cpp -o hello `llvm-config --ldflags --libs --system-libs`
>
> To Run: ./hello  input.bc